# Migrations been added to root folder not migration folder

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am trying to set up migrations for Nestjs TypeORM, in my `TypeOrmModule.forRoot()` i have added the desired folder for the migrations, but it keeps adding the migrations to the root folder.

```
TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
  type: 'mssql',
  host: 'test',
  port: 1,
  username: 'test',
  password: 'test',
  database: 'test',
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/entities/*{.ts,.js}'],
  synchronize: false,
  options: {
    useUTC: true,
  },
  migrations: [__dirname + '/**/migration/*.ts'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: __dirname + '/**/migration',
  },
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, I just added the `-d` option in the CLI command to specify the directory , like this :

```
ts-node ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:generate -n migration -d src/infrastructure/migrations
```

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be because of when you create a migration you're probably using the typeorm package right? (like so `typeorm migration:create -n PostRefactoring`). Which will use an entirely different config to that which you've specified in your nest application. The easiest way I suppose would be to create an env file and use `TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR` to define your migration directory.

See here for available env options http://typeorm.io/#/using-ormconfig/using-environment-variables. You can then link up your envs with your application so they're defined in one place.

I don't want to be that person that goes around advertising their own packages, you could easily achieve your own setup if you wish. I built a config module which you can use for typeorm configs like so

https://github.com/nestjs-community/nestjs-config#typeorm

```
import {Module} from '@nestjs/common';
import {ConfigModule, ConfigService} from 'nestjs-config';
import {TypeOrmModule} from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as path from 'path';

@Module({
    imports: [
        ConfigModule.load(path.resolve(__dirname, 'config/**/*.{ts,js}')),
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
            useFactory: (config: ConfigService) => config.get('database'),
            inject: [ConfigService],
        }),
    ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This would allow you to define your configs in a file like so

```
//src/config/database.ts
export default {
    type: 'mssql',
    host: process.env.TYPEORM_HOST,
    port: process.env.TYPEORM_PORT,
    username: process.env.TYPEORM_USERNAME,
    password: process.env.TYPEORM_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.TYPEORM_DATABASE,
    entities: [process.env.TYPEORM_ENTITIES],
    synchronize: process.env.TYPEORM_SYNCHRONIZE == 'true',
    migrationsDir: process.env.TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR
};
```

Then your .env

```
TYPEORM_HOST=test
TYPEORM_USERNAME=test
TYPEORM_PASSWORD=test
TYPEORM_PORT=1
TYPEORM_MIGRATIONS_DIR=src/migrations
```

Now you'll be able to use the `typeorm` command and you'll still have your database configs defined in one place. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and, for me, the issue was the connection name. My connection config was not using "default" as name, so we needed to pass its name to typeorm cli, like this:

```
typeorm migration:create -n MyMigration -c my-connection-name
```

Answer (score 2):

Just share my experience.
I have typeorm 0.2.12

1. I've configured typeorm script as described [here](https://typeorm.io/#/using-cli/installing-cli)
2. Created ormconfig.ts that exported config: `export = config;` (exactly)
3. Set migrationsDir without `__dirname` just `src/migrations`

And it work for me.

Answer (score 2):

In typeorm 0.3, I run:

```
npm run typeorm migration:create destination_path\name_migration
```

My package.json looks like this:

```
"scripts": {    
  "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs"
},
```

Comment: `"migration:generate": "typeorm migration:generate -d ./configs/typeorm.config.js ./db/migrations/NAME"`

Worked for me, thanks Diego!

Answer (score -1):

CLI command doesn't see (and doesn't know anything about exported name typeOrmConfig, so, it used default exported config if there is any). So, to make it work, the config should be exported by default. But because export default is a bad pattern, I rarely use it.

My example:

```
  // typeorm.config.ts file

  // Old code
  export const typeOrmConfig: TypeOrmModuleOptions = {
    type: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost' || process.env.DB_HOST,
    ...
  }

  // New code, make config visible for CLI commands
  module.exports = typeOrmConfig;
```

Comment: please explain this answer

Comment: CLI command doesn't see (and doesn't know anything about exported name `typeOrmConfig`, so, it used default exported config if there is any). So, to make it work, the config should be exported by default. But because export default is a bad pattern, I rarely use it.

Comment: @НиколайБугай it would be better if you edit the answer adding these changes. Thank you!